# In the triangle what is the least possible value of $y$?

Tags: geometry

A right triangle has side lengths $3,4,$ and $5$ units. Anther triangle has sides of length $4,x,$ and $y$ units and has the same area as the right triangle. If $x \leq y$, what is the smallest possible value of $y$? Express your answer in simplest radical form.

I can't think of any way to do this without using Heron's formula. That results in a multivariable quartic, so there must be a better way.

Comment: You are likely to hit the question cap of $50$ per month if you continue asking questions at this rate. Try to slow down and accept more answers.

Answer (score 4):

The area of the $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle is $6$ square units. If we place the $4$ side of our new triangle as the base, the altitude of the triangle must be $3$. The locus of points making the third vertex of a triangle with base $4$ and altitude $3$ is a line parallel to the $4$ side, as in this diagram.

[image]

I have renamed the unknown triangle sides $a$ and $b$, since $x$ and $y$ have other meanings in the plane. It is intuitively obvious, as well as easily provable, that $b\le a$ means that the top vertex $C$ of the triangle must be to the left of the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$. It is also obvious and easily provable that the smallest value of $a$ with that constraint is when the third vertex is just above midpoint of $\overline{AB}$, point $D$ in my diagram. The Pythagorean Theorem then tells us that $a=\sqrt{2^2+3^2}=\sqrt{13}$.

Answer (score 0):

For each $y$, we can find the maximum area (which we denote by $M(y)$) it can be. It can be clearly seen that $M(y)$ is continuous and increasing. If the area of the triangle is not the maximum area given $y$, by Intermediate Value Theorem, since $M(2)=0$ (degenerate case) and $M(y)>6$, there exist some $y^\prime$ such that $M(y^\prime)=6$. As $M(y)$ is increasing, we have $y^\prime<y$. Hence, we want the area of the other triangle to be maximised when we fix $y$.

We now show that to maximise the area of the other triangle, we set $x=y$. Let's fix $y$ and vary $x$ towards $y$.

[image]

It can be seen that the height of the triangle is increased when we increase $x$ to $y$, so the area is increased.

Now, $x=y$. To get the area easily, we can use Pythagoras Theorem to get the height of the triangle, which is $\sqrt{y^2-4}$. Hence, we have the following area equation:

$6=\frac{1}{2}\times4\times\sqrt{y^2-4}$

This gives $\sqrt{y^2-4}=3$, so $y=\sqrt{13}$.

Comment: The correct answer is $\sqrt{13}$.

Comment: Oops, will fix calculation mistake

Comment: Why did you want to maximize the area?

Comment: Why is it the case that the minimum value of $y$ will occur when $x$ and $y$ are equal?

Comment: @Puzzled417, added explanation.